# null entry for parameter 'id'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary

All the similar topics are resolved ,but I cant find similar mistake as mine.

Model :

```
public class CountriesViewModel
{
    public int BuffId { get; set; }
    public string CountryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

View :

```
    @model List<BTGHRM.Models.CountriesViewModel>
    @{ 
        WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model, canSort: false, rowsPerPage: 15);
        int row = 0;
    }


    @if (Model.Any())
    {

        @grid.GetHtml(
                tableStyle: "table",
                headerStyle: "table_HeaderStyle",
                footerStyle: "table_PagerStyle",
                rowStyle: "table_RowStyle",
                alternatingRowStyle: "table_AlternatingRowStyle",
                selectedRowStyle: "table_SelectedRowStyle",
                columns: grid.Columns(

                grid.Column("Name", @Resources.Localization.country, format: @<text>
                        <span class="display-mode"><label id="NameLabel">@item.Name</label></span>
                        @Html.TextBox("Model[" + (++row - 1).ToString() + "].Name", (object)item.Name, new { @class = "edit-mode" })
                </text>, style: "p40"),

                      grid.Column("", "", format: @<text>
                        @Html.Hidden("Model[" + (row - 1).ToString() + "].BuffId", (object)item.BuffId, new { @class = "edit-mode" })
                    </text>, style: "p13"),

            grid.Column("", "", format: @<text>
                        <a href="DeleteCountryRecord/@item.BuffId" id="@item.BuffId" class="link_button delete-button display-mode">@Resources.Localization.delete</a>
            </text>)
                )
            )
    }
```

I`d like to delete row by sending its id (buffId) in action method :

```
public ActionResult DeleteCountryRecord(int BuffId)
    {
        using (var db = new HRMEntities())
        {
            Country RemovableLine = db.Countries.Find(BuffId);
            try
            {
                db.Countries.Remove(RemovableLine);
            }
            catch
            {
                TempData["Message"] = App_GlobalResources.Localization.error;
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("CountryCodes");
    }
```

I get all the Ids right, but i have mistake

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'BuffId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult DeleteCountryRecord(Int32)' in 'BTGHRM.Controllers.AdministrationController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters

But in the link which is genered on click of the button can see, that id is posted right :

> http://localhost:59763/Administration/DeleteCountryRecord/17

What could be my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to ensure a route is defined that specifically names `BuffId`. That, or you can rename the parameter to `id` in your action method signature, assuming that default is in your routing table.

If you add a new route, it would go with the rest of your routing (probably RouteConfig.cs), and make sure it goes above the default one:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DeleteCountryRecord",
    url: "Administration/DeleteCountryRecord/{BuffId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Administration", action = "DeleteCountryRecord" }
);
```